# I cannot get $_POST in php from js ajax in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

This is my **php** file:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_mon_action', 'mon_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_mon_action', 'mon_action' );

function mon_action() {

    if (isset($_POST["form_data"])) {
        $field1=$_POST["form_data"];
    }else{
        $field1='heye';
    }
    var_dump($_POST);
    die();
}
```

And this is **js** file:

```
function sayHelloWorld() {
    window.alert('hey');
    var div = document.getElementById('alt_textarea');
    var div_tmp = document.createElement('div');
    div_tmp.innerHTML = div.innerHTML;
    var images = Array.prototype.slice.call(div_tmp.getElementsByTagName('img'));
    var form_data = new FormData();
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        var altImage = document.createTextNode("articleImage_" + i);
        images[i].parentNode.insertBefore(altImage,images[i]);
        images[i].parentNode.removeChild(images[i]);
        form_data.append('eyecatch[]',images[i].src);
    }; 
    form_data.append('body',div_tmp.innerHTML);
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'admin-ajax.php',//I wrote absolute path here.
        type:'POST',
        data: { 
             'action': "mon_action",
            'form_data': form_data
        },
        timeout:10000
    }).done(function(data) {
          window.alert(data);
    }).fail(function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          window.alert("error");              
    });
}
```

But `var_dump($_POST)` did not work.
My `window.alert` stops only with 'hey'.
When I change to "formdata: 'some strings'" in data in js file, I can use `var_dump($_POST)`.
So my question is why I cannot use `$_POST` when I use these files. 
Please tell me.

Comment: 1. You need a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) or a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) object to do a file upload with FormData. 2. All data must be placed in the FormData object. 3. Uploading files with $.ajax arguments. 4. In PHP you use $_FILES with file uploads.

Comment: Thank you for answering this problem. When I do not send image and send only some strings, var_dump($_POST) does not work.  Could you tell me why this problem occurs?